# Does frequency of mechanical vibration of material affect its blackbody radiation spectrum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics

Can we see the difference in emissivity for instance between the same object vibrating in two different frequencies ?

Answer (score 0):

No.  The frequency of EM radiation such as visible light is many orders of magnitude greater than the frequency of mechanical vibrations.  You would not be able to detect any difference in the spectrum even if there was a difference.